# VSCode Remote SSH to a docker container running on GCP VM

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, ssh, vscode-remote

I have a GCP VM with a running container essentially containing some custom python environment.

```
~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND       CREATED       STATUS         PORTS     NAMES
123456789101   python:3.9.18-bookworm   "/bin/bash"   3 hours ago   Up 6 seconds             test_docker_env
```

Note that it's launched with a command "/bin/bash" as I intend to use it to edit code from VSCode and have an option to run&debug it within the container.

There are two ingredients that I am trying to combine:

1. VSCode Remote SSH extension
2. Option to pass `--container` flag to `gcloud compute ssh` command
   https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers#connecting_to_a_container_using_ssh

For the first ingredient, I can successfully SSH into the VM (but not into container). To do so, I can look at the output of `gcloud compute ssh` output with `--dry-run`:

```
gcloud compute ssh myinstance --tunnel-through-iap --dry-run
```

and then edit ProxyCommand in .ssh/config file accordingly to include something like:

```
HOST compute.12345
    HOSTNAME compute.12345
    ...
    ProxyCommand .\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\python.exe -S .\google-cloud-sdk\lib\gcloud.py compute start-iap-tunnel myinstance %p --listen-on-stdin --project=myproject --zone=us-east1-c --verbosity=warning
    ...
```

For the second part, I can successfully SSH into a container running on the VM by passing the option `--container test_docker_env` (my container has this name assigned via `docker run --name test_docker_env`)

```
gcloud compute ssh myinstance --container test_docker_env --tunnel-through-iap
```

Now, the issue is that I can't pass `--container` argument via the ProxyCommand in .ssh/config file. Also, passing `--dry-run` flag to `gcloud compute ssh` ignores container argument which isn't helpful.

If I simply edit .ssh/config by appending `--container test_docker_env` in the end of ProxyCommand, and then use VSCode Remote SSH extension, then the log suggests that it isn't parsed the way I need:

```
> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.start-iap-tunnel) unrecognized arguments:
>   --container (did you mean '--account'?)
```

Help, please? I am new to the business and would appreciate little prerequisites to answers